# Problems with the AVD Manager - It doesn't launch

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have an annoying problem that the AVD Manager.exe does not launch. When I press the icon, the commander shows up and then immediately closed, and gives the message: "failed to execute tools\android.bat error 2. The System cannot find the file specified".
when I try to open it from eclipse, through the "Device" window, it says: "Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".

the weird part is when I run my app, it opens the last virtual device that I was working on, but I can open only this one, so I can't check if my application runs on another android versions or devices with different specifications. My main problem is that I can't open the AVD Manager at all, and I can't choose the virtual device that I want to run my app on.

Comment: Try re-installing the Android SDK, worst case.

Answer (score 0):

click in .../SDK/tools/android.bat 
if this file is executed  your sdk haven't error Otherwise you must re install SDK

Answer (score 0):

Before you uninstall your SDK, make sure `AVD Manager.exe` and `SDK Manager.exe` are in the `sdk` directory of the Android SDK. If they already are, you might want to reinstall the SDK.

This happened to me last week and moving the exe's solved the problem. For some reason AVD Manager and SDK Manager were not in the correct directory when installing Android Studio.